# CentOS server migration (physical type of migration only HDD)

Tags: linux, hard-drive, migration, centos-8, physical-environment

I need your help regarding "phyisical" migration of the CentOS server. At the moment my CentOS is installed on the C220 Cisco server, but in next couple of weeks I will get another C220 that will be installed in the rack above the current server. I want to migrate CentOS from the old C220 to a new C220 server.

My question is, can I do that by only moving HDDs from the old server to the new server, and vice versa?

Kind regards,

Belphegor

Comment: Also, if you have any additional tips for this type of migration feel free to let me know. Thank you in advance!

Comment: The Centos installation or applications may depend on hardware and software properties that are different in the second server. Examples: UUIDs of other storage devices; MAC addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed ESXi on another server, and I migrated previous CentOS by going though all the services that were installed, then I would install the same services on the new CentOS and I would copy configuration files from the old to the new machine.